Why can't I inherit scale as a property in AE?
As far as I understand, there is parenting by layers and individual properties. When inheritance goes by layer, then it occurs relative to the parent anchor point. But I need to make it so that the scale of the child can animate relative to its own anchor point. But for some reason, I can't inherit scale as a property. I can inherit scale only with the entire layer. What's the problem here?

